# Buscar lista de archivos en un directorio .bat

Tags: windows, script, batch

estoy intentando crear un .bat que a partir de un txt (que contiene nombres de ficheros) busque en un directorio.

Ejemplo del txt:

```
hola.txt
juego.exe
listacompra.txt
```

A partir de esta lista, lo que necesito es buscar en un directorio, por ejemplo en `c:\`, en que carpetas se encuentran.

¿Teneis alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien. Yo parto de un documento con un listado de nombres de ficheros/programas. Necesito recorrer ese documento(es un txt) y buscar en todo el disco duro (c:) si existe algún archivo que tenga ese nombre. Una vez que haga la primera búsqueda, que guarde el resultado en otro documento y vuelva a leer el listado para coger el segundo nombre de la y buscar de nuevo. Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 1):

mi archivo list.txt contiene lo siguiente:

hola.txt

chao.txt

En mi disco C existe una carpeta de nombre ***folder*** donde deje un txt de nombre hola.txt, lo hice así para no buscar en todo el disco, si no demoraria mucho buscando, así que mi respuesta te sirve de base.

Los comandos a continuación imprimen **existe** para hola.txt y **no existe** para chao.txt

```
@echo off

FOR /F %%i IN (list.txt) DO (
    @echo %%i 
     IF exist c:\folder\%%i ( echo c:\%%i existe ) ELSE ( echo no existe)
  )
PAUSE
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias pero creo que no me expliqué bien. Yo parto de un documento con un listado de nombres de ficheros/programas. Necesito recorrer ese documento(es un txt) y buscar en todo el disco duro (c:) si existe algún archivo que tenga ese nombre. Una vez que haga la primera búsqueda, que guarde el resultado en otro ducumento y vuelva a leer el listado para coger el segundo nombre de la lista

Comment: @maricarmen modifique mi respuesta para lo que necesitas

Answer (score 1):

Esta script debería de funcionar:

```
@echo off
cd C:\
for /f "tokens=*" %%B in (nombres.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do (
        find "%%~A" >>filepath.txt
        )
    )
```

Lo que hace es recorrer todos los directorios y subdirectorios desde C:\ buscando cada uno de los archivos dentro del .txt junto a sus respectivas rutas y cuando los encuentra los almacena en un archivo llamado "filepath.txt" situado en la misma ruta donde ejecutaste en archivo bat.
El punto negativo es que tarda mucho en terminar su trabajo ya que tiene que recorrer el disco por completo. 
Espero que te sirva ^^

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el comando `dir` para cada fichero que leas del txt:

```
dir nombreDirectorio /s/b nombreFichero
```

`/s` indica que busque recursivamente en el directorio especificado (el actual si no se especifica) y todos los subdirectorios. `/b` hace que la salida tenga un formato más simple.

Comment: Buenas, gracias pero creo que no me expliqué bien. Yo parto de un documento con un listado de nombres de ficheros/programas. Necesito recorrer ese documento(es un txt) y buscar en todo el disco duro (c:) si existe algún archivo que tenga ese nombre. Una vez que haga la primera búsqueda, que guarde el resultado en otro documento y vuelva a leer el listado para coger el segundo nombre de la lista. Muchas gracias